# Flink offset went to inconsistent state on manually resetting kafka offset

Tags: apache-kafka, flink-streaming

We have a flink stream app which reads msg from kafka.
Due to some reason we had to reset kafka offset to latest from kafka reset command as there was huge pile up. We wanted flink app to skip all these msg and start from new message which would come after reset.

The problem is since flink manages its offset internally it is not aware of this reset and it's now reading msg from backward only (offset point before resetting) and now not able to commit offset also. Hence on every restart of flink app it again read from the same point. So we have duplicate msg on every restart.

I understand that we should not reset offset manually in flink kafka app. But how do we recover from this.

I have tried to set auto.offset.config to latest also still it reads those messages again.

Comment: Are you restarting your Flink app from a savepoint/checkpoint? If so, are you doing so because there is other state (besides the kafka offsets) that are you trying to preserve?

Comment: Checkpoint is enabled with default time for checkpointing. There is no savepoint. We reset the offset from kafla command direclty. There are no other state we are preserving. We want our flink app to read msg from latest kafka offset but the problem is flink offset is different (as we marually reset offset to latest from kafla). How can we recover from getting these msg again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when Flink is recovering from a failure or being manually restarted from a savepoint or checkpoint will it use the offsets recorded in a checkpoint or savepoint.

Otherwise, the Flink Kafka consumers will start reading from the consumer group's committed offsets in the Kafka brokers, or from the offsets you have explicitly specified in your code, i.e.,

```java
myConsumer.setStartFromEarliest();     // start from the earliest record possible
myConsumer.setStartFromLatest();       // start from the latest record
myConsumer.setStartFromTimestamp(...); // start from specified epoch timestamp (msecs)
myConsumer.setStartFromGroupOffsets(); // the default behaviour
```

I'm not sure how to reconcile these facts with what you have reported.

Comment: You mean if we disable checkpoint/savepoint it will read from offset specified by kafka? But i will need to make code change for this. Is there any other way to gracefully handle this?

Comment: You can leave checkpointing enabled. But do not launch the job in the mode where it loads its state from a checkpoint or savepoint.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: The behavior you want is the default. There must be something overriding this, either in the application code, or in some deployment automation.

Comment: When i set myConsumer.setStartFromLatest(); it read from latest offset, but when i remove that it again start from very old offset. since we have manually messed up with kafka (using kafka command) flink is not able to commit any offset now. How to recover from this.

Comment: You could change the consumer group ID.

Comment: the point is we dont want to read from begining if we change the consumer id, it will start reading all the messages which has been processed again. Is there any way strategic way to recover from this?

Comment: Some of what you are reporting should not be possible. Since there are things going on in your environment that don't add up, I don't know what you should do.

Comment: let me rephrase, 1. I have manually reset offset from kafka command. 2. Since its a manual reset flink is not aware of it. 3. So its not able to commit the offset now. 4. when I setStartFromLatest that time it consumer from latest though but when i remove setstartFromLatest to read from earliest committed and run again it again reads from begining offset. that  means its not able to commit the offset.